# Abelian subvarieties of abelian varieties --- reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, reference-request

This question may be too naive, in which case I apologise in
advance. Anyway, it is a well-known fact (see e.g. Milne's notes)
that any abelian variety A has only finitely many direct factors
up to automorphisms of A. (Here a *direct factor* of A is an
abelian subvariety B for which there exists another abelian
subvariety C of A such that $A \cong B \times C$.)

My question is: how much is known about the corresponding
question for *arbitrary* abelian subvarieties, rather than
direct factors? That is, is it known whether every abelian
variety A has finitely many abelian subvarieties, up to
automorphisms of A? If not, what's the best known result in this
direction?

I've asked a couple of people about this, and their opinion seems
to be that it's "more or less" known. But I would like
something a little more concrete, if possible. Any relevant
references would be appreciated!

Comment: Over the complex numbers this is just a purely elementary linear algebra question in disguise. Did you try thinking about it this way?

Comment: According to Poincaré's Complete reducibility theorem every abelian
variety is isogenous to the product of simple abelian varieties with
the reasonably expected uniqueness condition on the factors. You
should be able to find this theorem in any standard book on abelian
varieties, say, Mumford's or Birkenhake-Lange.

(I moved this here since it is more of a comment than an answer and it certainly was not meant to be an answer.)

Comment: Here is a copy of BCnrd's comment that would probably disappear with the deletion of the answer that he made the comment to. So this is a comment to the above comment:
$$\quad $$
Since the question is sensitive to the distinction between End(A) and End0(A), even reducing the problem to the isotypic cases seems an unwise strategy. But the Poincare reducibility theorem does show that the abelian subvarieties are the images of endomorphisms, so the problem reduces to a question about orders in finite-dimensional semisimple Q-algebras (and more specifically, Albert algebras). – BCnrd 1 hour ago

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. @BCnrd: I got that far, but the sticking point was that it seems necessary to know that the endomorphisms involved have bounded eigenvalues. I don't see how to get that yet, so I'd better think some more. 

Answer (score 7):

For the benefit of others who might look at this question, let me mention that I found the following reference proving exactly what I wanted. (More precisely, I was told about it by David Ploog.)

Lenstra, H; Oort, F; Zarhin, Yu. *Abelian subvarieties*. J. Algebra 180 (1996), no. 2, 513–516.

Comment: http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~hwl/PUBLICATIONS/1996b/art.pdf

Comment: Now, Kani shows in (http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/hum-msm.pdf) a result that was already well known, that if an abelian surface contains at least 3 elliptic subgroups (i.e. abelian subvarieties), then it contains infinitely many.

Comment: An example of this would be the self product of an elliptic curve $E$; just take $E_n:=\{(z,nz):z\in E\}$ in $E^2$; this gives an abelian subvariety for every $n$.